# Draw google chart with dynamic data from json

Tags: json, charts, google-visualization

I need to display google chart with dynamic json data. In this case it is a gauge chart with only one json item:

```
{
  "Label": "1",
  "Waterlevel": "82"
}
```

My code generates no error. But also no chart will be generated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['gauge']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getWaterLevel',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function (jsonData) {
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

                data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
                data.addColumn('number', 'Waterlevel');

                for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                    data.addRow([jsonData[i].Label, jsonData[i].Waterlevel]);
                }

                var options = {
                    width: 400, height: 120,
                    redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
                    yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
                    minorTicks: 5
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('waterlevel_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);

                console.log(jsonData);
            }
        });
    }

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

</script>
<div id="waterlevel_div" style=""></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the values for `Waterlevel` in the json are represented by strings,
which need to be converted to numbers.

try using `parseFloat`...

```
parseFloat(jsonData[i].Waterlevel)
```

---

**EDIT**: Seems to work fine here, with hard-coded json.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['gauge']
}).then(function () {

  var jsonData = {
      "Label": "1",
      "Waterlevel": 82
  };

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Waterlevel');

  var row = [];
  for (var key in jsonData) {
    row.push(jsonData[key]);
  }
  data.addRow(row);

  var options = {
      width: 400, height: 120,
      redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
      yellowFrom:75, yellowTo: 90,
      minorTicks: 5
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('waterlevel_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="waterlevel_div"></div>
```

---

**Note**: you're using an old version of google charts, which should no longer be used.
recommend using the newer library `loader.js`

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

instead of `jsapi`, according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader from now on.

this will only change the `load` statement, see [Update Library Loader Code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code)...

Comment: Thanks, it is now an interger but still no chart appears

Comment: I added a working snippet above, check your browser's console for errors (press F12). Not included in your post, but have you included the html `<div>` element? as well as the `.js` file? see above...

Comment: Your snipped work fine, also in my app. But my code still doesn´t work :(  I checked all div tags and json again. There are also no JS error in the console.

Comment: have you updated to the new version, `loader.js`? and you're sure the `success` function is being called, try writing a message to the console inside `success` -- `console.log('test');`

Comment: Yes version is up to date now. Success function is also called. It works also if i replace the foreach with hard code data.addRow(["1", 82]);. Something in relation with the json goes wrong here. console.log(jsonData); inside foreach will not be called

Comment: and you're sure the values are integers, if I hard-code `"82"`, no chart. if I use `82` it appears, or `parseInt(jsonData[i].Waterlevel)`

Comment: Yes sure  {"Label":"1","Waterlevel":82} ... same result. But shouldn´t apper this inside foreach - console.log('Something'); ?

Comment: aah, your json is not inside an array, sorry I didn't notice earlier, you need a different type of for loop, changed snippet above. still need `"1", 82`...

Comment: Great, thank you very much!  single line data.addRow([jsonData.Label,jsonData.Waterlevel]) - instead of foreach the json - did it also in this case with only one item!